# React ViteJs css module priority order

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, styled-components, vite

My project is React with **ViteJs** and I use Material UI as the basis of my theme and components.
However, in some components, for code readability (because some elements need multiple style property lines); I opted to create a module.scss file alongside to separate the behavior (tsx, jsx) and the style (scss).

My concern is that the custom styles I put in this .module.scss file has a lower priority than MUI. However, it is supposed to be an overload of what is by default given by MUI.

For this cause, I am obliged to put a whole '!important'; which is not clean.

Hence my question is, how to put the `<style>` of the MUI before the `<style>` of the css module in `<head>`, so that they are applied behind those of the MUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MUI [documentation says](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#css-injection-order-3), you need to use `<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>` as wrapper for your component tree. Here is a [working example from documentation](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-modules-nuyg8?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: Before, I put it (<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>) only in components that uses a .module.scss file. Now, I just put it in a higher level (wrap the main <App> directly) and it works. I don't really see the difference or why but at least I solved the problem. thank you